# Unresolved external function while linking Ocaml and C

Tags: gcc, linker, ocaml

I am trying to wrap C code to link it with OCaml.

Got the code to compile fine, but linking does not work.

My ML test code:

```
external deal: int * int -> bool = "caml_deal"

let (bool) =
  deal(1, 1)
```

I also have a stub:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CAML_NAME_SPACE
#include <caml/mlvalues.h>
#include <caml/memory.h>
#include "clang_deal.h"

CAMLprim value
caml_deal(value ml_tuple)
{
    CAMLparam1( ml_tuple );
    int players = Int_val(Field(ml_tuple, 0));
    int treshold = Int_val(Field(ml_tuple, 1));
    int res = deal(players, treshold);
    return Val_bool(players);
}
```

My deal is defined as:

```
#include "utils.h"

int deal(int players, int treshold) {
  dealer d{};
  return d.deal(players, treshold);
};
```

I am able to compile the code fine. Like:

```
$ ocamlc -c test_stubs.c
$ gcc -c clang_deal.cpp -std=c++17 -I./pbc/include
$ ocamlc -c test.ml
```

When I try linking, it raises an error:

```
$ ocamlc -o dealer test.cmo test_stubs.o clang_deal.o
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Error while linking test.cmo:
The external function `caml_deal' is not available
```

The `nm(1)` shows that `caml_deal` is defined in the text segment.

```
$ nm test_stubs.o
0000000000000000 T _caml_deal
                 U _caml_local_roots
                 U _deal
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Generally you have to list modules in "topological" order. I.e., you need to list a module before the other modules that use it. I will test to see if this solves your problem.

**Update**

Looking more closely I see a few problems, or at least things that I would not expect to work.

Your stub code is written in C, but it calls out to a function written in C++. C++ is designed specifically to be able to call C functions, but the reverse isn't true in general as far as I've heard.

Your final compilation uses `ocamlc` which produces bytecodes. I don't think you can easily link bytecodes with arbitrary external native code. You can probably do so if you produce a "custom" bytecode interpreter, which isn't what you want.

If I change the code to all C, if I add some top-level code to test.ml, and if I use `ocamlopt` to do the final compilation and link, things work for me as follows.

```
$ cat clang_deal.c
int deal (int players, int threshold)
{
    return !!(players + threshold);
}

$ cat test.ml
external deal: int * int -> bool = "caml_deal"

let (bool) = deal (1, 1)

let main () = Printf.printf "%b\n" bool

let ()  = main ()

$ ocamlopt -o deal clang_deal.c test_stubs.c test.ml
$ ./deal
true
```

This doesn't seem to be exactly what you want to do, but maybe it will get you past the first problem or two.

As a side comment, it's not clear that you realize that `bool` is just an ordinary variable name in your `test.ml`. Putting it in parentheses is not required, and doesn't change the meaning (to or from a type name, say).

Comment: Ocaml supports using C code in bytecode with a few differences. Specifically functions with more than 5 arguments follow a different calling convention for bytecode and native code. See the manual for details.

Comment: C++ code can be used from ocaml as well but requires the use of `external "C"` or using the c++ mangled name in either the ocaml file or the stub. As the name mangling is architecture dependent that is a bad idea. In my code I declare the stubs as `extern "C"` and compile them as c++.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your help. I figured out what was the problem.

My exported function caml_deal() was defined hence there was `_caml_deal` in the text segment. However, I failed to link one of the libraries on which C++ code relied (and yes, I had `extern "C"` in the header). Turns out if C/C++ code is missing a symbol or symbols, `ocamlopt` reports the problem as an unavailable with the top-level function. In a way, it even makes sense. Though, for newbies like myself, a more detailed error would have been more insightful.

Comment: I don't think that your interpretation of the problem is correct. No `ocamlopt` will not just randomly pick a function and report it as an unavailable. Moreover, ocamlopt will use your system linker, so no surprises here. I believe, that the real reason whas that order in which you have specified your object files. In OCaml it should in the topological order, as Jeffrey told already - it should be `test_stub.cmo test.cmo` not the other way around.